# Consulta mongoose con condicional

Tags: mongodb, sql

Quisiera hacer una consulta de todos los archivos que tengan como id_folder 'CJJ3' o 'NQPM', sin embargo en la consulta solo puedo poner un parametro, hay alguna forma de hacer esto? El código que tengo es el siguiente

```
 File.find({id_folder: 'CJJ3'}, '_id, name').exec(function(err, files){
    if(err){
      console.log("Error");
    }else{
      res.json(files);
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes el operador $or que te lo soluciona. en la documentación tienes mas detalle. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

```
File.find({ $or: [ {id_folder: 'CJJ3'}, {id_folder: 'NQPM'} ]}, '_id, name').exec(function(err, files){
    if(err){
      console.log("Error");
    }else{
      res.json(files);
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución para lo que necesitaba, seria algo como:

```
File.find({
    $and: [{ $or: [{id_folder: 'X7QX'}, {id_folder: 'CJJ3'}] }]}, '_id, name').exec(function(err, files){
    if(err){
      console.log("Error");
    }else{
      res.json(files);
    }
  })
```